# Color approximation

Tags: image, colors

Let's suppose we have a regular RGB image. Now we would want to approximate the color of each individual pixel of our source image with a color out of a small set of colors.

For example, all tones of red should be converted to that specific red out of my set of colors, same goes for green, blue, etc.

Is there any elegant way/algorithm to achieve this?

Comment: Nearest in Eucledian distance in the RGB space is the most common one.

Comment: Id go with what jongware said.  Each pixel usually has some of each, so you would want to find the one with the most defining color.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Should I calculate the color distance in RGB or some other color space in order to come closer to the human perception?

Comment: you want to convert the image to the small set of colors?

Comment: @Muhammad Yeah, that's right.

Comment: I am not sure but the following link may help you http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html

Comment: Thank you, I've come up with a solution in python myself, although it is fairly slow(30s for an image of 640x480 with a target color space of size 20)